# Close window after junit test

Tags: java, testing, junit, swt

So I've got a Junit test (fragment) that looks like

```
String buffer="Mary had a little lamb";
r.decodeSWT(buffer, false, new GraphDrawingForSWT());
assertTrue((r.getNumberOfNodesInGraph() == 8) && (r.getNumberOfEdgesInGraph() == 7));
```

My problem is that the decodeSWT method opens a window showing a diagram, and the test will not proceed until it's closed.  Is there a best-practice way to override this from the test? It's obviously making it difficult to automatically run the tests.

Comment: What is "r" in your example ? Also I second @DNA, can't you separate the code that managers the graph (and count nodes) from the code that displays it ?

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are generally a sign that your code needs refactoring so that the logic parts (e.g. constructing graphs) are cleanly separated from the GUI parts.

You can then test the logic part by inputting a string and testing the graph output (for example), and the GUI part by opening a GUI, giving it a graph, testing that some nodes are displayed (for example) and then closing the GUI from the test code.